# What exactly do I message an employer if I want to come back to their company?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, manager

I am a coop student, and I worked my first co-op placement at company X.

I performed really well, and the manager said "just let me know if you ever want to come back". We have even discussed me working full time after graduation.

I will be seeking for my next coop term in the winter, and I would like to apply for company X again.

I know that I should notify my manager that I have done this, because chances are that he will hire me if I do so.

I don't know what exactly to message him though.

Here is what I have:

Dear John Doe,

It was a pleasure working for company X, and I would like to do it once again. I have submitted a job application for this position at X, and just thought I'd let you know about this.

Hope we can work together again soon.

Is this good enough, or can it be improved?

Comment: So the old boss doesn't have a position, and you'll be back at the same company in a different position and expect at some point to run into him/her?

Comment: Sounds great to me!

Answer (score 1):

> Dear John Doe,
>   It was a pleasure working for company X, and I would like to do it once again.

"Dear John Doe,
"It was a pleasure working *with you at* company X, and I would like to do it once again."

> I have submitted a job application for this position at X, and just thought I'd let you know about this.

I have submitted an application to return to X for the Winter term; wanted to make sure you knew.

> Hope we can work together again soon.

Hope we can work together again soon.  *(no suggestions)*